# What is difference between /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt and /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.trust.crt in centos7?

Tags: ssl, centos7

I am using certificates signed by CA file for securing kubernetes API. For that I added my CA file say ca.crt to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` and used the command `$ update-ca-trust` to add it to the trusted list. I found my certificate in `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt` file and also in `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.trust.crt` file with some appended string of 20 (not exactly) characters. Why there are these two files and what is difference between them ?

Comment: If you have a CA bundle you are *not* using self-signed certificates.

Comment: I edited my question accordingly...

Answer (score 4):

@YogeshJilhawar:Tls ca file which is signed by private institute must be added to the ca-bundle files on OS(such as centos7.x),but there is a little different(bwtween ca-bundle.crt with ca-bundle.trust.crt) as following:

ca-bundle.crt contains a list of CA certificates trusted for TLS server authentication usage without distrust information.

ca-bundle.trust.crt contains a list of CA certificates which includes trust (and/or distrust) flags specific to certificate usage.

Both files contain CA certificates in the extended BEGIN/END TRUSTED CERTIFICATE file format.

What's more,ca-trust-source contains low priority source configurations but ca-trust/source contains high priority source configurations.Good luck!

Comment: What do the terms "low priority source configurations" and "high priority source configurations" mean?